# How can I stop a specific role from speaking in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So, right now I'm trying to make a specific role not able to talk in a channel. I have code that works, but only restricts the `ctx.guild.default_role`(@everyone) from talking.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'''We have logged in as {bot.user.name}''')
  
@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(manage_channels=True)
@commands.bot_has_guild_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lock(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    await ctx.send('**An admin/moderator has locked this channel. Please wait for an admin to unlock this channel with `+unlock`.**')
    print(f'{ctx.author} locked channel {ctx.channel}')

@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(manage_channels=True)
@commands.bot_has_guild_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def unlock(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=True)
    await ctx.send('**An admin/moderator has unlocked this channel with `unlock`.**')
    print(f'{ctx.author} unlocked channel {ctx.channel}.')

keep_alive()
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Can someone please help me?

Restated Question: I need a role like "peasant role" not be able to talk, and @everyone role is still able to talk in that channel when an admin says something.

Thanks people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TextChannel.set_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions) and [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.utils.get) as follows:

```
await ctx.channel.set_permissions(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name='Foo'), send_messages=False)
```

`discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name='Foo')` gets a discord role by name.